# Adding other variables to a univariate forecast

Tags: forecasting

So let's say that I am trying to better a forecast that I have. The forecast that I have comes from a demand planning system at work and takes into account seasonality and yearly trends based on historical data from typically the previous 36 months (the forecast is monthly).

I am hoping to add some extraneous factors to this forecast to see how they might impact it. In a sense, some of these factors may be picked up in the seasonal effects from the current forecast but others may not be. I will be testing lags and leads for these variables as well.

How would I go about adding the impacts of these additional variables to the forecast that I currently have? My only current thought would just be to run some sort of time series regression to determine the impacts that the extraneous variables have and add these impacts to the current forecast.

Are there any other ways that I can do this? Any advise would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: I don't think there is a simple way to do this. Probably the simplest is to run Arima with external predictors (the additional variables). But if you think that X at t+1 will impact y at t+2 (or even at t+1) you have to forecast what X will be in the future. For each variables you predict with.